# I'm already using a functional component and I keep getting error : Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

Hello I'm trying to use hooks in my component but I keep getting this message :
Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.

There are three common reasons you might be seeing it:

You might have mismatching versions of React and React DOM.
You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks.
You might have more than one copy of React in the same app.

although my react version is 17.0.2 my react dom version is 17.0.2 and my react native version is 0.64.2

here is my code

```js
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Alert, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

import {
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItemList,
  DrawerItem,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { GoogleSignin, statusCodes } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';

const CustomSidebarMenu = (props) => {
  const[user,setUser] = useState({})
    
    signOut = async () => {
        try {
          await GoogleSignin.revokeAccess();
          await GoogleSignin.signOut();
          this.setState({ user: null }); // Remember to remove the user from your app's state as well
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      };

      getCurrentUser = async () => {
        
        const currentUser = await GoogleSignin.getCurrentUser();
        setUser(currentUser)
  
      };

  return (
    <View style={stylesSidebar.sideMenuContainer}>
      <View style={stylesSidebar.profileHeader}>
        <View style={stylesSidebar.profileHeaderPicCircle}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 25, color: '#307ecc'}}>
            {'A'.charAt(0)}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <Text >
            {user}
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={stylesSidebar.profileHeaderLine} />

      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />

          
        
        <DrawerItem
          label={({color}) => 
            <Text style={{color: '#d8d8d8'}}>
              Déconnexion
            </Text>
          }
          onPress={() => {
            props.navigation.toggleDrawer();
            Alert.alert(
              'Déconnexion',
              'Vous êtes sur?',
              [
                {
                  text: 'Annuler',
                  onPress: () => {
                    return null;
                  },
                },
                {
                  text: 'Confirmer',
                  onPress: () => {
                    AsyncStorage.clear();
                    props.navigation.replace('Auth');
                    signOut();
                  },
                },
              ],
              {cancelable: false},
            );
          }}
        />
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default CustomSidebarMenu;

const stylesSidebar = StyleSheet.create({
  sideMenuContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#307ecc',
    paddingTop: 40,
    color: 'white',
  },
  profileHeader: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#307ecc',
    padding: 15,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  profileHeaderPicCircle: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    borderRadius: 60 / 2,
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  profileHeaderText: {
    color: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  profileHeaderLine: {
    height: 1,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#e2e2e2',
    marginTop: 15,
  },
});
```

Comment: It sounds like it's a problem with where you *use* `CustomSidebarMenu` (which you haven't shown). The error indicates you're just calling it as a function, not using it as a component function. Separately, the contents of your `signOut` function seem odd: it has a `this.setState` call in it, as though this were a class component.

Comment: Your code is also falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html): you never declare `signOut` or `getCurrentUser`. (I strongly recommend using strict mode so that's the error it always should have been.)

Comment: Or just use a function declaration rather than a function expression.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you forgot to change the `this.setState` to `setUser` in signOut

```js
   

    const signOut = async () => {
        try {
          await GoogleSignin.revokeAccess();
          await GoogleSignin.signOut();
          setUser(null); // Remember to remove the user from your app's state as well
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to declare `const` in your function

```
 const signOut = async () => {
        try {
          await GoogleSignin.revokeAccess();
          await GoogleSignin.signOut();
          this.setState({ user: null }); // Remember to remove the user from your app's state as well
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      };

      const getCurrentUser = async () => {
        
        const currentUser = await GoogleSignin.getCurrentUser();
        setUser(currentUser)
  
      };
```

or

```
async function signOut() {}
async function getCurrentUser() {}
```

Comment: That may be true, but it wouldn't trigger the error the question is about.